# How to think about protocols such as cellular, LoRaWAN etc. in IoT sensors vs GPS in terms of location tracking?

Tags: gps, iot, lorawan

Not sure if this is the right exchange for this question (but I don't see any other super relevant exchange). For context: I am trying to understand what are all the location tracking capabilities in IoT sensors. Specifically, the question is, if I want to track location of a sensor, is GPS the only answer, or are cellular, LoRaWAN, etc. also provide location tracking through non-GPS means?

Answer (score 0):

GPS positions can both be transferred via GSM and via LoRaWAN.

A rough position tracking is possible via GSM by determining the mobile base station.

If the signals of a device are received by multiple LoRaWAN gateways it is possible to determine the device position from the different times of receipt. But this requires LoRaWAN gateways with high precision timestamps. Cf. https://gridlocate.com/blog/lora-geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough guide on location sensing:

1. Outdoor Coarse (Few Kilometres) - GSM Traingulation
2. Outdoor Fine (+- 10 Metres) - Satellite Positioning (GPS, GLONASS etc)
3. Indoor Coarse (+- 1 Metre)  - Bluetooth 4.x, Bluetooth 5.0, WiFi
4. Indoor Fine (+-10 to 20 cm) - Bluetooth 5.2, Ultra Wide Band (UWB)
5. Altitude Fine* - Barometer

*  Does not work reliably in pressurised environments such as aircrafts and submarines